# Chang the product price when custom checkbox is selected in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I need to be able to change the product price when a custom checkbox is selected.  I want to add $10.00 for engraving on one product and $20 to other products for engraving.  I can't add it as a variant in Shopify because they handle inventory based off variants.  I am using the Debut theme.  I have the custom checkbox working in liquid and the textbox show/hide functioning.

Comment: Shopify doesn't do dynamic price changes on its own - like David Lazar says, a product's price is its price, and the only way Shopify lets you change that is to add extra products to the cart representing the difference in price.  With a bit of code under-the-hood in your theme, you can then hide that extra product to make it look like a single product to the shopper, even though it'll come in to your admin as two separate line items. There are several apps that will handle this for you if you are willing to pay for a service- I work at Bold, and can highly recommend our Product Options app :)

Answer (score 1):

When someone checks the box for engraving, what they are doing is say, put a $10 product in my cart to go with this product. That $10 product is an engraving. You can use line item properties to glue the product with the engraving. When the customer clicks add to cart, you add both the product and the engraving to the cart, glued together with the line item properties. The reason? In the cart if they remove the product, you can also remove the engraving. Brilliant right! This pattern is common, and has been used to secure billions in sales... have fun!

Comment: Well played with that this morning and got about as far as before - where can I change the price?  Used this link - https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/features/get-customization-information-for-products  Again not seeing where I can update the price of the item rather in the cart or on the product page.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You cannot update prices. That explains why you are finding it hard to find that option. It is not something one does. A variant's price will always just be it's price. Extras like engraving etc are represented by an additional product.

Comment: HMMM but engraving is not a separate product - it is an add on cost to the original product.  I am dumbfounded that this is even difficult.

Comment: Don't be dumbfounded... you could always just create a variant with an extra $10 on it called my_product_with_engraving too. Simple.

Comment: The problem with this is effects the inventory.

Comment: Yes. Which is why I suggested you follow the well established pattern from the very beginnings of Shopify and small customizations like this. Add an engraving product worth $10 to the cart for each product with an engraving and move on.